# The integral in "The Number 23" movie; What is it?

Tags: calculus, probability, ordinary-differential-equations

I was watching a movie called The Number 23 and saw this mathematical expression, I was wondering if it has any meaning and if it is, What does it mean?

[Here you can -Or Can't- see the expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh8Fl.jpg)

It's not very clear, but I **Think** it's written like this: $$\triangledown x G=\int_{0}^{1} t\triangledown x(px\frac{\mathrm{d} r}{\mathrm{d} t})dt $$

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd rather read $$\nabla\times G=\int_0^1t\,\nabla\times\left(F\times\dfrac{dr}{d\rho}\right)dt$$ but that does not ring a bell.

Comment: The integration bounds and the factor $t$ are unexpected.

Comment: My bet is that, as with most math in pop media, it's utter nonsense. But I don't blame you for asking!

Comment: Amazing attention to detail , visit Reddit movie details . I watched that movie and missed the math totally